# SQL query with mysql variable in like statement?

Tags: mysql

I want to select/check a value in a text column based on another column value like

```
SELECT tableA.randomID, wp_posts.post_content, wp_posts.ID
FROM tableA, wp_posts 
WHERE wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%tableA.randomID%' 
AND tableA.randomID = '110507B2VU'
```

But that didn't work, how do i set the LIKE statement

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT tableA.randomID, wp_posts.post_content, wp_posts.ID
FROM tableA, wp_posts 
WHERE wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%110507B2VU%'
```

Answer (score 17):

When you enclose something in quotes - its taken as a literal value, so in your first query - where you put `LIKE '%tableA.randomID%'` - MySQL is actually treating that as a string.

Without the quotes, it will take the value - ie:

```
WHERE something LIKE tableA.randomID
```

This will actually compare 'something' to the value of tableA.randomID, rather than the literal string.

To then include your % wildcards to make your LIKE statement different to an 'equals' comparison, try the [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function.

```
WHERE something LIKE CONCAT("%",tableA.randomID,"%")
```

Which will, if the value of tableA.randomID was say.. '`banana`' actually end up being this:

```
WHERE something LIKE '%banana%'
```

I hope I explained that clearly enough ;-)

Answer (score 5):

you can use the concat() with like

```
like concat('%',variable_name,'%')
```

In your case

```
SELECT tableA.randomID, wp_posts.post_content, wp_posts.ID
FROM tableA, wp_posts 
WHERE wp_posts.post_content LIKE CONCAT('%',tableA.randomID,'%')
AND tableA.randomID = '110507B2VU'
```